# Ubuntu 16.10 Software Center "cannot install from unsigned repo"

Tags: updates, software-center, repository

I'm new to Linux (Kubuntu 16.10) and I got 5 new updates concerning Intel-Drivers in the Software Center.

But after clicking on "Update" and trying to install those Updates, I only get the message `Cannot install from unsigned repo`.

Now how can I install those drivers ?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal by using CTRL+ALT+T and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will tell you that packages are signed with an untrusted key XYZ. You can select Y/N to manually force the installation of untrusted packages or you can tell Ubuntu you trust the key using the command:

```
 sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv XYZ
```